# 'Working with Minio and Dask I get s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_client'

Tags: boto3, dask, minio, botocore

Attempting to read from minio with boto3 and input into Dask

I am getting:

```
's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_client'
```

I set up boto with:

```
import botocore, os
from botocore.client import Config
from botocore.session import Session

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
  endpoint_url='https://example.org',
  aws_access_key_id=key,
  aws_secret_access_key=secret,
  config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
  region_name='us-east-1')

os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'
```

At these point, things seem fine and a simple test of:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
     print(bucket.name)
```

Will connect with no errors and return the bucket list I expect.

However, moving to Dask with

```
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import ResponseError
import io, sys, dask, s3fs
import pandas as pd
import dask.bag as db
import json

df = db.read_text('s3://mybucket/prefa/prefb/*.jsonld', storage_options={"session": s3}).map(json.loads)
```

results in

```
...
's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'create_client'
```

I'm really stumped here and looking for guidance.
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "session" should be a botocore session object, not a boto3 resource. You would be better off passing the various arguments in the client_kwargs parameter.

```
df = db.read_text(
    's3://mybucket/prefa/prefb/*.jsonld', 
    storage_options={"client_kwargs": 
        dict(endpoint_url='https://example.org', ...)}
    ).map(json.loads)
```

(see the docs of s3fs for the full set of arguments you can pass using storage_options)

Comment: Thanks I was able to get this working now..   looking something like:

```
dgraphs = db.read_text('s3://mybucket/prefa/prefb/*.jsonld', 
      storage_options={
          "key": key,
          "secret": secret,
          "client_kwargs": {"endpoint_url":"https://example.org"}
          }).map(json.loads)

```